# Edit shortcuts with invalid paths

Tags: windows, file-shortcut

I often need to create or edit a shortcut (a .lnk file) for an other computer.
Of course the path that is defined in these shortcuts is not always valid for my computer since I don't have the same permissions or the same application installed on my PC.

Example of the error:
[image: Problem with Shortcut]

How can I make Windows shut up, ignore this and let me edit shortcuts?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we can make invalid links through VBScript.

```
Sub Shortcut(Application,Name,Location,Icon,Hotkey)
  Dim objShell,DesktopPath,objShortCut,MyTab
  Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  MyTab = Split(Application,"\")
  If Name = "" Then
    Name = MyTab(UBound(MyTab))
  End if
  Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(DblQuote(Location & "\" & Name & ".lnk"))
  objShortCut.TargetPath = DblQuote(Application)
  ObjShortCut.IconLocation = Icon
  ObjShortCut.Hotkey = Hotkey
  objShortCut.Save
End Sub
Sub DblQuote(Str)
  DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Sub
```

And Call in script like:

```
Call Shortcut("C:\InvalidDestination","Invalid Shortcut","C:\","shell32.dll,47","CTRL+ALT+N")
```

Answer (score 2):

I modified the answer by @Wasif Hasan

Create a new text file with the extension `.vbs` (e.g. `C:\Temp\createShortcut.vbs`) and paste the following code snippet:

```vba
Sub CreateShortcut(Application, arguments, Name, OutputFolder, Icon, Hotkey)
    If arguments <> "" Then arguments = " " & arguments

    With CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").CreateShortcut(OutputFolder & "\" & Name & ".lnk")
        .TargetPath = Application
        .arguments = arguments
        .WorkingDirectory = Left(Application, InStrRev(Application, "\"))
        .IconLocation = Icon
        .Hotkey = Hotkey
        .Save
    End With
End Sub

Dim Application, arguments, Name, OutputFolder, Icon, Hotkey

Application = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
arguments = "http://www.google.com"
Name = "Shortcut to Google"
OutputFolder = "C:\Temp\"
Icon = "shell32.dll,47"
Hotkey = "CTRL+ALT+N"

Call CreateShortcut( Application, arguments, Name, OutputFolder, Icon, Hotkey)
```

Edit the arguments:

`Application`, `arguments` , `Name`, `OutputFolder` , `Icon` , `Hotkey`

Then save.

Open CMD and run `wscript "C:\Temp\createShortcut.vbs"`

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 will not let you edit / make an invalid link.

Make a folder c:\temp and copy the Link file to c:\temp. Now see if you can edit it there. You would need an editor like Ultra Edit or such like. Even in c:\temp the link wants to open normally.